# Move vertices of a generic UIView

Tags: objective-c

Is there any way to move the vertices of a UIView just like the images?
[image: imageOne]
[image: imageTwo]

*As a non-english native I really don't know the name of those points, so I'm using the term `external point`, but if you suggest the real name I'll edit it for sure.*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Every view is a rectangle, you can't change that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sven move individually some external point of a UIView. (some method like `moveExternalPoint:(int)pointRef toPoint:(CGPoint)pt`, being pointRef an integer that goes from 1 to 4, top left/top right/bottom left/bottom right)

Comment: Yes, but why? Do you want to distort the content of that view? And what kind of view do you want to edit, just any random view or some special custom view? Or do you just need a view where the user can draw any four-cornered shape by moving the vertices?

Comment: I want to distort the content of that view, it's an UIView that would have those point moved as some scrollView's scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a 3D effect, you can apply 3D transforms to the `CALayer` of the `UIView` like this:

```
CATransform3D   perspectiveMtx = CATransform3DIdentity;
perspectiveMtx.m34 = -1.0f / 100.0f;
CATransform3D   rotMtx = CATransform3DRotate(perspectiveMtx, angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
someView.layer.transform = rotMtx;
```

You may be able to simulate the distortion you want using 3D transforms, but if you really want a pure 2D distortion then you will probably have to use OpenGL directly to specify custom vertex positions.

Comment: Is there any way that the content also distort (with the main view)?

Comment: Yes, the content of the view will distort when you apply the transform to it.